# "eine multikulturell funktionierende Demokratie"

Tags: preposition, adjective-ending

In einer Zeitung habe ich den folgenden Satz gelesen:

> Oberflächlich betrachtet, gibt Brasilien ein gutes Beispiel **für eine
>   multikulturell funktionierende Demokratie**.

Soll das Präpositionalobjekt nicht **für eine multikulturelle funktionierende Demokratie** lauten?

Laut der Regel der Adjektive, sollen Adjektive innerhalb eines Präpositionalobjektes in Bezug auf beide, das Präpositionalwort und das Nomen, die sie bestimmen, dekliniert werden. Also, in diesem Fall: Was kann die Erklärung sein?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Deine Frage ist unabhängig von der Objekteigenschaft oder der Präposition. Es kommt hier nur darauf an, was bestimmt wird:

> eine multikulturell funktionierende Demokratie

Das Wort *multikulturell* bestimmt *funktionierend* genauer. Es handelt sich also um eine Hierarchie von Eigenschaften. *Multikulturell* wird als Adverb benutzt.

> eine multikulturelle funktionierende Demokratie

Das Wort *multikulturell* bestimmt *Demokratie* genauer, es handelt sich um eine Liste von Eigenschaften, die gleichberechtigt nebeneinander stehen. *Multikulturell* wird als Attribut benutzt.

Das klappt mit Adjektiven und Partizipien an beiden Positionen gleichermaßen:

> bunt schimmernde Schuppen — bunte(,) schmimmernde Schuppen
>
> die kreischend laute Säge — die kreischende(,) laute Säge
>
> ein lächerlich kurzer Applaus — ein lächerlicher(,) kurzer Applaus

Comment: Danke für deine Antwort. Könntest du mir bitte sagen, wie dieses Phenomenon in der Grammatik heißt?

Comment: Adjektive/Partizipien können *prädikativ*, *adverbial* oder *attributiv* verwendet werden. Du kennst offensichtlich nur die attributive Verwendung, die man daran erkennt, dass das Adjektiv/Partizip dekliniert wird. Aber schon wenn du sagst *Die Antwort ist gut.* verwendest du das Adjektiv *gut*, ohne es zu deklinieren: hier als *Prädikativ* (man sieht das neben der fehlenden Endung am Verb *sein*).

Comment: Ich kenne die drei Verwendungen von Adjektive und Partizipien. Jedoch wusste ich nicht, dass zwei Adjevtive nur auf einen bestimmten Nomen beziehen können, wenn sie durch ein Komma getrennt sind. Also, in diesem Fall könnte "eine multikulturell funktionierende Demokratie" als "eine Demokratie, die multikulturell funktioniert" auch formuliert werden.

Comment: Das Komma ist optional. Man kann es verwenden, um den Leser auf die Liste gleichberechtigter Eigenschaften hinzuweisen, oder um Gruppen zu trennen. Das ist vor allem dann sinnvoll, wenn man die adverbialen und attributiven Adjektive wild mischt. *Eine schöne kleine, leicht nachgemachte Übung.*

Comment: Ja, *eine multikulturell funktionierende Demokratie* und *eine Demokratie, die multikulturell funktioniert* sind von der Bedeutung her identisch.